# How to put variable into JSON

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, pushsharp

Actually I'm working with PushSharp. I would like to send notification but I have to put variable into this JSON instead of hardcoded text (below example).

```
var msg = "TEST MESSAGE";
    push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(registrationId)
                             .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"HERE MESSAGE\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}"));
```

Is it possible? How can I put msg variable into

I tried something like this:

```
push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(registrationId)
                         .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"{0}\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}",msg));
```

but it says: No overload for method `'WithJson'` takes '3' arguments.

Any idea's how to solve this problem?

Comment: ... `WithJson(string.Format("{\"alert\":\"{0}\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}",msg))` ...

Comment: I have never used PushSharp but there must be better ways to handle json other than forming it from string manually.  Suppose your msg contains `"`. What would happen?

Comment: I tried this out. Now I get this error.  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add your message into JSON you could do this:

```
var msg = "my message"; // this would be set somewhere else in the code
var jsonObject = {
    "alert" : "{0}",
    "badge" : "7",
    "sound" : "sound.caf",
    "msg" : msg
};

// convert the object into a string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(registrationId)
        .WithJson(jsonString));
```

**Edit:** I changed the code so you don't have to manipulate the string. Instead you can now manipulate the jsonObject. JSON.stringify converts it into a string then.

Comment: Thanks. :) Could you mark it as an answer if it solved your problem? That's be awesome. :D

Comment: Unfortunately, your edited code above doesn't work. Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `:', expecting `,' or `}'. The previous version works perfect.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/74eBt/
What do you have in your msg variable?